# Using grep to match md5 hashes

Tags: regex, linux, string, grep

How can I match md5 hashes with the grep command?

In php I used this regular expression pattern in the past:

```
/^[0-9a-f]{32}$/i
```

But I tried:

```
grep '/^[0-9a-f]{32}$/i' filename
grep '[0-9a-f]{32}$/' filename
grep '[0-9a-f]{32}' filename
```

And other variants, but I am not getting anything as output, and i know for sure the file contains md5 hashes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want this:

```
grep -e "[0-9a-f]\{32\}" filename
```

Or more like, based on your file format description, this:

```
grep -e ":[0-9a-f]\{32\}" filename
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, given the format of your file, the first variant won't work because you are trying to match the beginning of the line.

Given the following file contents:

```
a1:52:d048015ed740ae1d9e6998021e2f8c97
b2:667:1012245bb91c01fa42a24a84cf0fb8f8
c3:42:
d4:999:85478c902b2da783517ac560db4d4622
```

The following should work to show you which lines have the md5:

```
grep -E -i '[0-9a-f]{32}$' input.txt

a1:52:d048015ed740ae1d9e6998021e2f8c97
b2:667:1012245bb91c01fa42a24a84cf0fb8f8
d4:999:85478c902b2da783517ac560db4d4622
```

-E for extended regular expression support, and -i for ignore care in the pattern and the input file.

If you want to find the lines that don't match, try

```
grep -E -i -v '[0-9a-f]{32}$' input.txt
```

The -v inverts the match, so it shows you the lines that don't have an MD5.

Comment: Err... didn't the original question have a description of the file he was grepping through?  The answers we've provided don't entirely make sense in the new, less detailed, question.

Comment: +1 for taking the effort to explain what was causing the failed match by grep.

Answer (score 0):

Meh.

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS=: read filename filesize hash
do
  if [ -z "$hash" ]
  then
    echo "$filename"
  fi
done < hashes.lst
```

Answer (score 0):

A little one-liner which works cross platform on Linux and OSX, only returning the MD5 hash value (replace `YOURFILE` with your filename):

```
[ "$(uname)" = "Darwin" ] && { MD5CMD=md5; } || { MD5CMD=md5sum; } \
    && { ${MD5CMD} YOURFILE | grep -o "[a-fA-F0-9]\{32\}"; }
```

Example:

```
$ touch YOURFILE
$ [ "$(uname)" = "Darwin" ] && { MD5CMD=md5; } || { MD5CMD=md5sum; } && { ${MD5CMD} YOURFILE | grep -o "[a-fA-F0-9]\{32\}"; }
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```