# One-liner in ubuntu/macos to print checksum of a file

Tags: bash, macos, ubuntu

Is there a short one-liner to get a file checksum, which works on both macos and ubuntu? It doesn't matter what algorithm or program, as long as I don't have to install or setup anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use **[`OpenSSL`](https://www.openssl.org)**, and the commands should be the same:

```
openssl sha256 filename | awk -F'= ' '{print $2}' # optional
```

Use whatever hashing algorithm you want, `sha256`, `sha1`, `md5`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you can use `md5sum file`; on macOS, just `md5 file`. Both are default at a clean install, AFAIK. If you require that the command be the same, you can create an [alias](https://www.tecmint.com/create-alias-in-linux/).

Comment: But the output format differs, too. If you want to integrate them into a script, you want to avoid having to write extra parsing code.

Comment: If it needs to be integrated in a script, you don't need a quick one-liner; you can take the time to write a wrapper function.

Answer (score 1):

Just try both of them:

```
md5 file 2>/dev/null; md5sum file 2>/dev/null;
```

That line will work on both OSs, running both commands and discarding the one that gives an error, it will print only the valid result.

Comment: I tried this, but I didn't get it to work with piping the output. Not even `$(md5 ... )` worked.

Answer (score 0):

With a quick OS check you can use either md5 (mac) or md5sum (ubuntu), alternatively you could alias one of them so you'd be using the same command on either OS.

Comment: I'm looking for a one-liner that doesn't require any setup. `sha1sum` and `shasum` differs in name as well.

Comment: I'm not sure you'd be able to pull it off without any setup. The following comment could be a starting point, but it seems like it'd be easier to set up a bash script for it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49538774/11192600

Answer (score 0):

May I be so impertinent as to suggest writing your own?

```
python -c 'import sys, hashlib;
m = hashlib.sha256(); 
m.update(open(sys.argv[1]).read());
print("\t".join([m.hexdigest(), sys.argv[1]]))' file
```

The semicolons are gratuitous here, but necessary if you really want to force the issue and make this a literal one-liner.

Comment: Perl makes for a much better one-liner: `perl -MDigest::MD5 -e 'printf "%s %s\n", $_, Digest::MD5::md5_hex(<$_>) foreach @ARGV' file1 file2 ...`.